# How to Aggregate the camel hdfs chunks into temporary file and read from it

Tags: java, apache-camel, hdfs

I have a route with camel hdfs component reads files from HDFS. camel HDFS component reads the files in chunks. So, how to aggregate all the chunks and write to file or any other output source. So that, it can later read by splitter with \n to read extract record by record and perform further processing.

Here the HDFS files are of large size.

Answer (score 0):

Read from HDFS using

```
<from uri="hdfs://server:port/path?owner=xxxxxx&amp;chunkSize=xxxxx&amp;pattern=xxxxx&amp;delay=xxxx&amp;initialDelay=xxxx&amp;readSuffix=xxxx&amp;connectOnStartup=xxxxx" />
```

this will read the chunks as per the chunk size, then aggregate them using

```
<aggregate strategyRef="aggregationStrategyRef">
<correlationExpression>
<simple>header.CamelFileName</simple>
</correlationExpression>
<completionPredicate>
***Specify the predicate***
</completionPredicate>       
<to uri="direct:routeNext"/>
</aggregate>
```

next step is to implement the bean for aggregationStrategyRef and register in camel JNDI registry.